# Can't add time to time in PHP

Tags: php

So I have this code:

```
$laikas = htmlspecialchars($_POST['rodymolaikas']);
$laikas = date( "H:i:s", strtotime( $laikas ) );

  $videotrukme = $_POST['videotrukme'];
  $videotrukme1 = round($videotrukme);
  $videotrukme2 = sprintf('%02d:%02d:%02d', ($videotrukme1/3600),($videotrukme/60%60), $videotrukme%60);

$laikas_end = date('H:i:s', strtotime($laikas) + strtotime($videotrukme2));

echo $laikas_end;
```

The variables are even to:

```
$laikas = 17:00:00;
$videotrukme2 = 00:01:12;
```

But the answer I get is:

```
laikas_end = 02:00:00
```

Could you please tell me why is that happening?

Comment: take out `'$laikas'` and make it `$laikas` in `strtotime($laikas)`

Comment: `strtotime('$laikas')` won't work the way you expect. Get rid of the quotes. Same for `strtotime('$videotrukme2')`. Then read up on the difference between single and double quotes in PHP, as it'll continue to trip you up if you don't.

Comment: @ceejayoz I removed the quotes, then the answer becomes `06:32:56`

Comment: That's because the result of `strtotime` will be a UNIX timestamp (the current UNIX timestamp is about `1496691070`). Adding two of them together will give you a date in the 2060s right now. Print out your values and debug accordingly.

Comment: @ceejayoz Well, never thought that adding time may be so hard, lol. I'm new to PHP so have no idea what You're talking about. But thanks for the tip,bro!

Comment: You probably want to tinker around with stuff like http://php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php instead. Start by reading the docs of the functions you're using, though, and output values to the browser to see what they're being set to. The problems will usually become much more obvious at that point.

Comment: @Dr.Docttor you can go with my answer if it solve your problem of time addition

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish time addition like thi

```
<?php
$laikas = htmlspecialchars($_POST['rodymolaikas']);
$laikas = date( "H:i:s", strtotime( $laikas ) );
$videotrukme2 = $_POST['rodymolaikas'];
$videotrukme2 = date( "H:i:s", strtotime( $videotrukme2 ) );

$h =  strtotime($laikas);
$h2 = strtotime($videotrukme2);

$minute = date("i", $h2);
$second = date("s", $h2);
$hour = date("H", $h2);

$convert = strtotime("+$minute minutes", $h);
$convert = strtotime("+$second seconds", $convert);
$convert = strtotime("+$hour hours", $convert);
$laikas_end = date('H:i:s', $convert);

echo $laikas_end;
?>
```